# Shortcode pagination not advancing

Tags: functions, shortcode, query, pagination, gallery

I have a picture gallery that is working, I am converting it to a shortcode so the positioning can be flexible and I don't have to copy the code over and over again.

The issue I am having is that the pagination doesn't advance to the next page. The images show, the pagination shows, the page number shows...but when I try and click on page two or three the images, pagination, and page numbers don't change. The URL changes, the content doesn't.

I have a page with some manual code (that works and advances or changes when pagination is clicked).

The site I am working on is: http://joshrodg.com/test/banquet/2017-induction-banquet/. My test shortcode is on top (underneath 2017 Induction Banquet), the one that works, is the bottom one (manual code).

My shortcode looks like: `[halloffame rml_folder="16"]`

My function looks like:

```
function picture_gallery($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'rml_folder' => 1
    ), $atts));

    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    query_posts("post_status=inherit&post_type=attachment&rml_folder=".$rml_folder."&orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=12&paged=".$paged);

    if ( have_posts() ) :
        $return_string .= '<div id="album">';
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                $return_string .= '<div class="gallery">';
                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');
                    $return_string .= '<a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID).'" class="simplelightbox">'.$image.'</a>';
                    $return_string .= '<p>'.get_the_title().'</p>';
                $return_string .= '</div>';
            endwhile;
        $return_string .= '</div>';
    endif;

    $return_string .= '<div id="pagi">';
        $return_string .= '<div class="wrap">';
            $args = array(
                'prev_text' => __('<span class="left"></span><span class="ion-android-arrow-dropleft"></span>'),
                'next_text' => __('<span class="ion-android-arrow-dropright"></span><span class="right"></span>')
            );
            $return_string .= paginate_links($args);
        $return_string .= '</div>';
    $return_string .= '</div>';

    global $wp_query;
    $current_page = get_query_var( 'paged' );
    $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    $return_string .= '<p align="center">(Page: '.$current_page.' of '.$pages.')</p>';

    wp_reset_query();

    return $return_string;
}

function register_shortcodes(){
    add_shortcode('halloffame', 'picture_gallery');
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

Because this is working with the manual code, I'm guessing something is not quite right with my shortcode code.

Any ideas?

** UPDATE **

So, on the page http://joshrodg.com/test/banquet/, the pagination is broken, but on http://joshrodg.com/test/banquet/2017-induction-banquet/ the pagination works. `2017-induction-banquet` is the original post, it's a child post of http://joshrodg.com/test/banquet/. On http://joshrodg.com/test/banquet/, I am displaying the content of all my child pages. So, the shortcode itself is working, just not on this page - so there might be something wrong with my loop.

The loop for this page looks like:

```
<?php query_posts("order=asc&orderby=menu_order&posts_per_page=-1&post_type=page&post_parent=".$post->ID); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I'm thinking there might be a conflict with the loop in the shortcode and the loop on this page.

The pagination on the original page looks like: http://joshrodg.com/test/banquet/2017-induction-banquet/page/2/

The pagination on the parent page looks like: http://joshrodg.com/test/banquet/page/2/

Not sure if that makes a difference, but figured it's worth mentioning.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Have you verified that `get_query_var( 'paged' )` returns the correct page number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to find a solution.

I tried to change `query_posts` on my shortcode, but for some reason, I wasn't able to get that working. I changed the query on the page which fixed the issue.

The query now looks like:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'order' => 'asc',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => $post->ID

    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

The shortcode did not change (other than removing the hyphen).

So, the two queries were conflicting with each other. The different queries `query_posts` and `WP_Query` fixed the issue.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a hyphen in the shortcode name. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Hyphens .

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer. Could you expand upon why hyphens would mess up the shortcode's pagination?

Comment: The explanation is in the Code link specifically regarding hyphens in short codes. They are not recommended as they can cause inconsistent results, as explained in the Codex.

Comment: Hey there, I removed the hyphen, and the issue persists...still looking into this.

Comment: I did notice the shortcode works on the child page...but when the child page content is displayed on the parent page, that's when it breaks. I didn't realize this previously...so, the issue might be with the code I am using on the parent page - not with the shortcode itself. I have updated my original description of the issue.

Comment: It looks like you are using two queries: one for the loop, and one for the shortcode. I think (quick look) that the second query is replacing the first one (for the loop). Maybe this page will help? https://digwp.com/2011/09/3-ways-to-reset-the-wordpress-loop/

Comment: Both loops definitely include a query reset...but maybe if I use a different type of query besides just `query_posts` that could fix the issue...going to try a few things to see if something along those lines could fix the issue.